# Unknown small pitch wire to board connector

Tags: connector

Anyone know what series of connector this is?

Have tried to look at TE/AMP, Molex, Amphenol etc, but no luck.
Pitch about 1.5mm, but could be 1.25mm, 1.27mm or 0.05" (didn't have a calliper at hand).

On these boards the connector is SMT, no TH pins at all.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Typical JST type connector. Have you look at their catalog?

Comment: If you found the answer to your question, you are encouraged to post it with as much detail as possible (es. part number)

Comment: Did you have a different name @clab?

Comment: @Passerby no, always been the same

Answer (score 1):

OP has identified it as the JST brand ZH series connector, after a small reminder.

Answer (score 1):

It is a JST ZH-series connector.

Comment: Could you accept this answer (even though it's an answer to your own question)?  This way, the StackExchange system will not nag us that we have an open question.  Formality.